# std::deque - произвольный доступ

Tags: c++

Оказывается есть произвольный, а есть последовательный доступ через итераторы.

К примеру итераторы на std::vector и std::deque - поддерживают итераторы с произвольным доступом.
Итераторы std::list - только с произвольным.

С std::vector - понятно - все элементы - располагаются непрерывно в памяти.

Тепер понятно и с std::list - это список с произвольным расположением в памяти, который содержит указатель на предыдущий и последующий элементы - отсюда и последовательный доступ.

Но, если std::deque - точно так же, как и std::vector - поддерживает произвольный доступ - то чем он отличается от std::vector ?

Comment: создайте экземпляры этих контейнеров и увидите разницу

Comment: Вектор из векторов (фиксированного размера). В отличии от обычного вектора, нет риска перемещения ранее вставленных элементов при push_back.

Comment: Ну, например, быстрым не только `push_back`, но и `push_front`. Посмотрите эту [диаграмму](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCkOa.png).

Comment: @Chorkov, как это может быть вектор векторов и при этом  не быть риска перемещения ранее вставленных элементов при push_back ?

Comment: @Staxcelrom - нет риска перетряхивания всего контейнера - варианты рассмотрены в документации.

Comment: @Staxcelrom  считайте, что для вложенных векторов сразу делается reserve  под фиксированный размер.

Comment: @Chorkov, под вложенные вектора да, но reserve основного вектора когда инбудь закончится и ему придется сделать realloc.

Comment: @Staxcelrom перемещение  вектора, не требует перемещений вложенных объектов. Значит при реаллоке внешнего вектора, вложенные вектора будут перемещены, но содержащиеся в них объекты останутся на месте.

Comment: Тут объясняется что `deque` немного приукрашает производительность при вставке в начало, но константа так мала, что на практике (из-за конечного объёма памяти компьютера) не заметна: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl

Answer (score 1):

Главное отличие `deque` от `vector` - возможность О(1) вставки-удаления не только в конец, но и в начало (в отличие от О(n) для вектора - из-за необходисости полностью перемещать все данные).

Цена этого - то, что дек работает немного медленнее, и все свои данные НЕ хранит последовательно одним блоком в памяти.

P.S. Понравилась диаграмма он Harry, я ее тут добавлю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Сказанное Вами я вроде бы понимаю, однако я не понимаю другого - все верно std::deque имеет вставку в начало и в конец за О(1), в то время, как у std::vector - это  О(n), НО я не понимаю тогда, как при этом у std::deque - сохраняется произвольный доступ к элементам по итератору, как у std::vector, а не последовательный, как у std::list. Из диаграммы ни как не могу это понять.

Comment: Обычно deque содается в виде списка блоков. Поэтому его легче наращивать с обеих сторон, знание размеров блоков позволяет сделать индексированный доступ. Но немного медленнее, чем у вектора.